# Struts2 Action Mapping Results in Error 404

Tags: java, struts2

I have a Struts2 application running on a Glassfish 4 container. The application consists of one action class `SampleAction`

```
package com.mysample.action;
public class SampleAction {

 public String execute() {
    return "success";
 }
}
```

The struts XML is simple and consists of:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

     <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">

<struts>
        <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
                <action name="sayHello" class="com.mysample.action.SampleAction">
                        <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
                        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
                </action>
        </package>
</struts>
```

The web.xml for this project looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

When I go to http://localhost:8080/sample_war_exploded/sayHello.action **I get a 404 error. Not found**

When I go to: http://localhost:8080/sample_war_exploded/success.jsp   -- I get a success page

Why are my mappings not working correctly? I expect that by going to */sayHello.action, I would get the success page.

I have tried re-deploying the artifacts, stopping+restarting the server, etc. I even made a couple of changes to the content on the "success.jsp", and those changes are picked up when I re-deploy. The mappings aren't working right and I'd like to know how to fix this.

Comment: Did you misplace the configuration file?

Comment: Do you see any errors on application startup?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of experimenting, I figured this out. It turns out that Glassfish let me deploy my Struts2 application without throwing any errors, even though the Struts2 project library was not being correctly added to my project. I switched my deployment container to Tomcat, and I started receiving errors indicating that I was missing configurations. I was then able to add the missing configuration items and re-deploy the application. It is now working as expected.

Thanks for the comments/advice.